# macOS Big Sur SIP enable has a strange behaviour

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, code-signing, macos-big-sur

I have a Mac application that works on Big Sur with SIP disabled. But when I run the same application in SIP enabled system it crashes.

The crash log says

```
Crashed Thread : 0
Exception Type : EXC_CRASH(Code signature invalid)
Termination Reason : Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
```

But when I run the `codesign --verify --verbose` I see the following:

```
myApp.app: valid on disk

myApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Any help, guidance, suggestions etc are very welcome.

*Should you need any other information, please let me know. I will provide.*

Edit 1:

Using `-vvvd`

```
macos-11-big-sur:~ anoopvaidya$ codesign -vvvd /Applications/myApp.app/
Executable=/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp
Identifier=com.my.myapp
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20500 size=54276 flags=0x10000(runtime) hashes=1685+7 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=92c7351b0b1f45fd1300dfa51b9aed595d895b56
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=92c7351b0b1f45fd1300dfa51b9aed595d895b5622218031ee28d0fbfde937b2
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=92c7351b0b1f45fd1300dfa51b9aed595d895b5622218031ee28d0fbfde937b2
CMSDigestType=2
CDHash=92c7351b0b1f45fd1300dfa51b9aed595d895b56
Signature size=9029
Authority=Developer ID Application: MY TECHNOLOGIES, INC. (XXXXXXXXXX)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=07-Feb-2021 at 10:20:19 PM
Info.plist entries=20
TeamIdentifier=XXXXXXXXXX
Runtime Version=11.1.0
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=181
Internal requirements count=1 size=184
macos-11-big-sur:~ anoopvaidya$
```

Comment: try codesign -vvvd xxx.app for detail information

Comment: @season: Updated my question with the output

Comment: just guess... Do you enable App Sandbox/Hardened Runtime/etc in capabilities? And what kind of signing certificates you are using? Or run spctl -a -v xxx.app to see outputs

Comment: @season: no it is not sandboxed. But yes it has hardened runtime and extensions enabled.